# Duplication Issue with MySQL sorting on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, innodb, percona

For a given list of unique items, after sorting them based on a few columns in batches, I am getting duplication of items.

There are 2 tables:

```
- item_popularity_tbl:
  iid (UINT, PK)    pplt (UTINYINT)

- item_cat_id_tbl:
  iid (UINT, PK)    cid (UTINYINT)

Where:
  iid: item ID, unique values in the tables
  cid: cat ID, values in the range (1, 15). Multiple items can have same cid.
  pplt: popularity, vals in the range (1, 10). Multiple items can have same pplt.
```

Given a list of item ids, all unique, I need to order it by cid ASC and then pplt DESC.

I use the below SQL (using MySQL) code to achieve it:

```
# python code snippet
def db_get_items_sorted(conn, iid_list, offset, limit):
    n1 = ','.join( ['%s'] * len(iid_list) )
    #
    sql_stmt = ("SELECT a.iid, a.cid, b.pplt "
                "FROM pclg.item_cat_id_tbl      AS a "
          "INNER JOIN pclg.item_popularity_tbl  AS b ON b.iid=a.iid "
                "WHERE a.iid IN (%s) "
                "ORDER BY a.cid ASC, "
                         "b.pplt DESC "
                "LIMIT %s,%s") % (n1, offset, limit)
    #
    return conn.query(sql_stmt % tuple(iid_list))
```

I call db_get_items_sorted(...) in batches of 10. I tested this with input iid_list of 58 items (unique), against fully populated tables with unique iids. For each call, mysql returns unique 10 iids with proper sorting, as requested. But when I concatenate the batches to create the final 58 items, I notice that several items (iid) in the list are duplicated (and for those, all columns returned are same, basically complete duplication). For eg, 48 unique rows and 10 duplicates.

If I call db_get_items_sorted(...) with offset 0 and limit 58, there are no iid duplicates. However, I need to call in small batches as we can potentially do this sorting for several thousands of items, going forward.

Question is: how to achieve iid uniqueness across batches?

Comment: If a separate thread is inserting or deleting records as you do the batching, then `OFFSET` is messed up.

Comment: @RickJames That's a good point, Rick. However, in this case, that scenario is not there, kind of static tables at the moment. Using DISTINCT as mentioned by scaisEdge below solves the problem. But, not clear why we need DISTINCT and why duplication is happening.

Comment: `JOIN` inflates the number of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't like to use DISTINCT to solve the problem. I wasn't sure why the duplication of the rows was happening in the first place, hence wanted to address that.

Below is the fix, using a column iid with unique vals, in the ORDER BY:

```
     sql_stmt = ("SELECT a.iid, a.cid, b.pplt "
                    "FROM pclg.item_cat_id_tbl      AS a "
              "INNER JOIN pclg.item_popularity_tbl  AS b ON b.iid=a.iid "
                    "WHERE a.iid IN (%s) "
                    "ORDER BY a.cid ASC, "
                             "b.pplt DESC, a.iid DESC "
                    "LIMIT %s,%s") % (n1, offset, limit)
```

TL;DR:
The duplication was happening as we were using LIMIT along with ORDER BY and the columns used in ORDER BY didn't have unique vals.

Reasons:

- LIMIT returns the moment it finds out the required count of rows that satisfy the query.
- When a column with non-unique vals is used with ORDER BY, the rows holding the same vals of those columns do not need to have deterministic ordering.

So, using LIMIT and calling this routine multiple times (to finally concatenate them to produce the final result), mysql was running the ORDER BY several times and rows with same val for columns (used in ORDER BY) were non-ordered across those calls -- ie their positions were not constant.  LIMIT M,N however returns rows from the specific (M, N) window of the ORDER BY result.

This resulted in the final concatenated result holding duplicate rows.

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html

Answer (score 1):

You could work on query using distinct so it is the query itself that removes duplicates.

```
 sql_stmt = ("SELECT DISTINCT a.iid, a.cid, b.pplt "
                "FROM pclg.item_cat_id_tbl      AS a "
          "INNER JOIN pclg.item_popularity_tbl  AS b ON b.iid=a.iid "
                "WHERE a.iid IN (%s) "
                "ORDER BY a.cid ASC, "
                         "b.pplt DESC "
                "LIMIT %s,%s") % (n1, offset, limit)
```

Comment: Thank you, that should solve it. Will test it on my data and get back. A related use case with slight mod: what if iid is not 100% unique? Let's say it is used as timestamp (with mins granularity) for a comments table and there are instances of multiple comments added (held in another table) in same timestamp? If it helps, I can add this use case of mine to the query.

Comment: Obviously the distinct clause actually working on distinct values and therefore it is essential to choose the columns (or column representation) actually needed for your purpose .. in case of rows equal to less than values in the timestamp you can choose to group these values using functions time such minute (). or .hour or anything you like

Comment: Are you saying we use the unique comment_id there and use DISTINCT on it? (I have updated the query of mine).

Comment: Just for my better comprension .. you said that you have 58 row but only 48 are areally distinct  .. then you have more then a rows with the same iid? .. and you need  a way for manage each  row as unique .. and not as one of possible others indentical rows?

Comment: The complete description of the query is for question #1, where I used 58 unique/distinct iids for query. When I am doing it in batches (say 10 each with limit) I get 10 unique iid in each query but appending those results doesn't return 58 unique iids, but with 10 duplicate rows. I think your answer with DISTINCT solves this problem.

Comment: Regarding my question #2, I need a similar batch method where iid will be replaced by timestamp (minute granularity) -- in this case I cannot use DISTINCT as there can be duplicate timestamps but different comments in comment tbl -- how do I ensure that I get all the requested timestamps, if there are duplicates, then I get them if the columns differ.

Comment: In this case   a  proper data sample (minimal ) and the expected  result could help me a lot..  if you can please updated  your question with this sample for question 2

Comment: Sure, I will do that.

Comment: Then  .. i can take a look tomorrow .. is deep night in my conutry now ..

Comment: Sure, I have elaborated my 2nd query, with example. Tried to be more clear, as our online times don't overlap.

Comment: @Ethan   .  the data sample is clear but add the exact expected result for #2 please ..

Comment: Yesterday after updating the query #2, I realized that the answer to this is similar to your answer for #1 (using DISTINCT comment_id). For simplicity of this stackoverflow question asked, I think of deleting the #2, leaving only #1. Do you agree to that?

Comment: I' m Agree .. the concept essentially is the same  ..(There are some cases where you must select a line between similar results using aggregate functions but it is a whole other issue ..and if we will need investigate this case separately ).. I hope that my contribution will be useful result

Comment: Sure, agree. 1 final query regarding #1: I am doing it seeking for ~300 results but in batches of 10 thinking to not overload mysql. Is that a right assumption, or I can do more per batch?

Comment: For the database engine  ... the seeking  (select ) is pratically the same for  all the rows  in one batch or based on pagination (limit)  normally is the pagination limit the slow. one (the limit force the db for all the query (because is orderd )   and after select only the rows by limit) . could be instead the net /tlc charge but for tens of thousands of row.. .. hope is clear

Comment: Not very clear with the understanding of the last sentence "could be instead ... thousands of rows".

Comment: 300 lines there are no problems for mysql database .. you can have (perhaps) some problems (not related database) with the network if you receive from a remote server tens of thousands of lines ..

Comment: No problem with mysql db -- I thought if I am retrieving several colums in the select which do not have a wrapping Key (ie may not be on ram; using innodb) then the retreival of those columns of data per query will induce load on mysql (random access to disk) -- hence I thought of the load and did pagination (limit). Having limit of 10 (or more) may then have other simultaneous queries go though without having them wait for current 300 (or say 1K) to finish.

Comment: For my experience and knowledge is   much ... much better access to 300 lines all at once that access to 10 of these 300 lines from time to time. I repeat .. you might have trouble accessing to 30,000 lines. and then the paging would help you in particular as regards a pleasant user experience (expect the population of many rows can be annoying) while display 10 lines more quickly is more pleasant .. However this is only a benefit for the user since the database works more ..

Comment: Thank you for your answer and all the clarification. They have been very helpful!

Comment: Missed asking you: How to know early on that this query will misbehave by returning duplicates of {iid, cid, pplt} when such duplicates do not exist in db, so that I need to use DISTINCT to solve it? Or, is it that the usage of LIMIT like I did (ie concatenating sequential ones to yield final result) is prone to it ? It just happened that only one of my several test cases failed, for me to figure.

Comment: I don't uderstand  .. please post e new specific propely described question .. changing question time by time  made my crazy ..

Comment: This query was related to the first query to which you had answered with distinct usage. Nevermind, if it's confusing.